# Multiple IDistributedCache definitions are not closing redis connections

Tags: asp.net-core, redis

I have the following solution in order to implement multiple IDistributedCache definitions:

```
public interface IDBCache : IDistributedCache
{
}

public class DBCacheOptions : RedisCacheOptions { }

public class DBCache : RedisCache, IDBCache
{
    public DBCache(IOptions<DBCacheOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(optionsAccessor)
    {

    }
}
```

And I have other definitions like the above pointint to different redis instances.

I am registering the cache service at Startup.cs as:

```
services.Configure<DBCacheOptions>(options => options.Configuration = configuration.GetValue<string>("Cache:DB"));
services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IDBCache, DBCache>());
```

And then I am wrapping IDBCache as:

```
public class DBCacheManager
{
    private const string DB_CACHE_FORMAT = "DB:{0}";
    private const int DB_EXPIRATION_HOURS = 8;

    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;

    public DBCacheManager(IDBCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public Task AddDBItem(string name, string value)
    {
            return _cache.SetStringAsync(string.Format(DB_CACHE_FORMAT, name), value,
                new DistributedCacheEntryOptions { AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromDays(DB_EXPIRATION_HOURS) });
    }
}
```

And when I check for clients connected to redis (info clients command) connected_clients are incrementing without stopping, also when I see the clients list (client list command) I see the large connection list with long ages and idles.

Insights: I am using redis implementation of AWS ElasticCache which has unlimited idle timeout by default but I guess I should not be forcing to close these connections, should I? I suppose my application should be responsible.

Comment: This is a very good question, i have the same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bad implementation of dependency injection. IDistributedCache interface does not have implementation of redis INCR command so somewhere in our project we were connecting directly using StackExchange.Redis with a DI wrapper that was creating multiple connection multiplexers and IDatabases.

Bottom line: my bad